# Understanding the Wilcoxon rank-sum one-sided test

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

With a simple two sided test, the null hypothesis is often set as:

> Hn: µ1- µ2 = 0

and if we get a p-value less than 0.05, we can reject the null hypothesis and accept the alternative. That is:

> Ha: µ1 - µ2 != 0

But if we expect a difference, we can create a one-side test. Taking the example from [here](http://www.uni-kiel.de/psychologie/rexrepos/posts/npWilcoxon.html), we run a one-sided Wilcoxon rank-sum test test on the data.

```
set.seed(123)
Nj  <- c(20, 30)
DVa <- rnorm(Nj[1], mean= 95, sd=15)
DVb <- rnorm(Nj[2], mean=100, sd=15)
wIndDf <- data.frame(DV=c(DVa, DVb),
                     IV=factor(rep(1:2, Nj), labels=LETTERS[1:2]))
```

Not included on the original website, we can visualise the data

```
boxplot(DV ~ IV, data = wIndDf)
```

We also assess the levels of the data

```
levels(wIndDf$IV)
```

And we see that `A` will be compared to `B`. To run a one-side test, the code is as (direct from the website)

```
wilcox.test(DV ~ IV, alternative="less", conf.int=TRUE, data=wIndDf)
```

And we get a p-value < 0.05, so we can reject the null. **But what was the null, and the alternative**

From the `alternative` command, am I correct in saying the null is:

> µA < µB

Comment: What are $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ in your question?

Comment: @user08041991 is your question just how to order the one sided hypothesis for a two sample test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IV variable is a factor with two ordered levels, A and B. The A is the referent level and the B is the comparitor. The difference in location is of a A - B form. It's easy to check this by giving B a much larger mean and testing the "greater" and "less" commands. The presentation of the estimate and its CI is also the same as a T-test. A more interesting question is *what* exactly is lesser or greater with the Wilcoxon. The Wilcoxon has been questioned extensively as far as interpretation and credibility of results. It is not a median nor is it a mean unless strong distributional assumptions are met.